# MS SQL Server 2005 : Error log is too big and getting bigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, security

I guess someone tries to logon to our sql server and error log is getting bigger. I am running out of space on hdd. What should be the solution?

- Cleaning up error log regularly? Howto?
- Disabling access to SQL server? For attacker IPs? For local use only? Howto?
- Any other?

Regards,
Burak

Comment: Get a bigger hard drive?

Comment: Don't 'guess'. Look into the errorlog and see why its growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure logins are the cause of the error-log growth? If so, you could disable remote logins:

Goto START --> Microsoft SQL server 2005 --> Configuration Tools --> SQL server surface area configuration

Select Surface area con figuration for services..
Select Databas engine --> Remote connections and choose 'local only'

Note, this will disable all remote connections to the database, so only change this if your application connects locally!

Answer (score 2):

we had a similar problem here, constant attempts to guess the systems password filled up the log to epic proportions.

you could disable external access via the windows firewall (if you're using windows SBS 2003) its fairly trivial but the end solution we opted for (because we still required external access ourselfs to the database server) was to change the default access port to SQL server; it seemed to stop alot of problems.

although if possible, I would also considering changing the architecture of your network slightly (sometimes this isn't possible if you have purchased some virtual machine from a service provider); moving your database server and disconnecting it from your hub/switch and plugging it into the back of your web server (if this is the ultimate use for your databases) so the web server acts as a type of proxy, prevent all external internet access.

Answer (score 0):

For emergency you execute [`sp_cycle_errorlog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182512.aspx) to start a new one, so you can delete the old one w/o restarting the server.

But the million dollar question is, of course, what is filling up the errorlog? What message shows up again and again? If you tell us that, perhaps we can help you fix the problem and eliminate the errorlog growth.